# Can the Leibniz integral rule be applied to an integral whose integrand does not contain the variable of derivation?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, leibniz-integral-rule

To my understanding, the Leibniz Integral lets
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(x,t)dt$$
under certain restrictions. (Pretend the second $\frac{d}{dx}$ is a partial derivative, since I can't figure out how to do it).

I haven't seen the proof and the Wikipedia page is a bit dense for me, so I'm asking here. Can this rule also be applied in the case that $f(x,t) = f(t)$? My initial reaction makes me think "why not?", but if so, then any integral of that form would simply be $0$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)dt &= \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(t)dt\\
&= \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}0dt\\
&= 0\Big|_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
$$

So simply, can the Leibniz integral be applied to integrals of this form? And if so, why is the result valid? And if not, what assumption does the proof rest on that makes it so?

Comment: The first formula is false in general when $a, b$ are not constants.

Comment: It can, but you have to use the actual formula $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,dt=b'(x)f(x,b(x))-a'(x)f(x,a(x))+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\,dt$$

Comment: The command for $\partial$ is "partial".

Comment: If something applies to all functions of two variables then it applies, in particular, to those that happen not to depend on one of them.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I guess I forgot the formula I was using is a special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you are asking is:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt=\frac d{dx}\left[F(b(x))-F(a(x))\right]=b'(x)F'(b(x))-a'(x)F'(a(x))$$
$$=b'(x)f(b(x))-a'(x)f(a(x))$$